# Return with input if registration fails in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I know you can use:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput(Input::all());
```

In any form, but register has its own classes in Laravel 5 after using make:auth and I am not sure how to redirect with input if registration fails.

Any help?

Comment: This is/should be the normal/default behavior, why do you ask? What Laravel Version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation), this is exactly how Laravel will redirect you back with errors and the given input.

If registration fails in Laravel, you can redirect the page with input data and error name which is mention by you in the controller. So, below code will be more helpful.

```
return redirect()->back()
                       ->withInput($request->input())
                       ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag());
```